# Running a webapps from USB

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, express

I am new to Javascript frameworks and nodejs. Recently, I came across a requirement which made me think if I can use them.

Requirements:
--A lightweight website which can be run off a usb stick (kind of portable webapp) without a need to install a complete webserver on client machine. 
--The website should be available to users on the local network. The webapp will be maily used for (a)capturing user responses to a questionnaire (b) showing graphs, data, reports (c) showing clickable diagrams

I want to build a very responsive, rich-client kind of webapp.

From whatever I searched on the Internet, I think I should use node.js (as webserver) + express.js (MVC framework) + Twitter Bootstrap (for building nice UI).

I am not sure, if my choices of frameworks/tools is correct, so want to know what experts recommend.

Thanks.

Comment: A web application is accessed by a browser. Just like [SO]. And they require a server. What is the point of having to run a server on your own machine to access a local application? You either need a central web server and run your app off of that, or a portable desktop application connectionig to a central database. Another thought against the weird portable webapp concept: how are you going to make sure your users have their firewalls correctly set up, and no port collisions occur? Also, where will you store your data? How would one instance access the data of the other instances?

Comment: To be honest I think you need to rethink this strategy. I don't understand why you would want to have a portable web app? Surely the best way would be to host your web app on a local networked server then there will be no messing around with usb sticks to visit a website.

Comment: Maybe I left out the details:
(a)We don't want to host on central server. My thought was to run a webserver off the USBstick on the LAN. (this shouldn't cause firewall issue (b)Cannot use portable desktop appl. because we want other users on the local LAN to connect;the obvious choice is a website. 
(c) It is sufficient even if the data captured is stored on the USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

The only requirement is to download a portable version of node.js. For example, [windows x64 v0.8.18](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.18/x64/node.exe). All the distributables are located [here](http://nodejs.org/dist/).

That's all. All your modules need to be installed locally.

Comment: What do you mean as "portable" ? Is it so that XP and Vista/7 need  different executables? Anyway, a 32 bit version would probably run on more machines?

Comment: By "portable" I meant, a website which I can "carry" with me on a USB stick and launch it on any local network. Basically, I want the freedom to make my website available on demand to a limited audience (on a LAN) without me having to maintain a central webserver.

Comment: The portable version is just an executable that parses and executes node scripts so you can have your web server in your usb and execute it on any machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded and compiled node.js to evaluate. Great tool, builds and runs nice also under Ubuntu and is also supported on [Mac OS](https://sites.google.com/site/nodejsmacosx/) and Windows. Very interesting possibilities. Surely can be recommended.

To have it really cross platform, you can simply drop several nodejs executables for different platforms into NTFS formatted USB stick. Linux guys may need to tweak mounting permissions but they are used to.